# Change <video> parameter onclick using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change an object's parameter when the user clicks a link on the site which would reference another video.

HTML

```
<object id="myExperience8675309" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="480" />
  <param name="height" value="270" />
  <param name="playerID" value="123456789" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="abcdefghijklmnop" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
  <param name="@videoPlayer" value="8675309" />
</object>
```

I'm not sure how to access the parameters of the object via an onClick function. I want to change the @videoPlayer value. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using foo as an arbitrary trigger element:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementsByName('@videoPlayer')[0].value='123456';
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wbsTV/)**

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck on trying to access the object and then change the parameter and then the subsequent value. I'll give it a shot and if it works I'll be back to vote you up.

Answer (score 0):

you create a function in javascript that will go,

```
document.getElementsByName('@videoPlayer').value='New Value';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `document.querySelector` support (IE8+, at least for CSS2 selectors), you can use an attribute selector to get the parameter you want:

```
button = document.querySelector('button'); // <button> element
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var param = document.querySelector('[name="height"]'); // can use '#objectid [name="height"]' for greater specificity
  param.value = 100;

});
```

<kbd>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/orevar/1/)</kbd>